# URL Redirection with OneDrive for Business not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, onedrive-for-business

Environment: SharePoint 2013, OneDrive for Business (ODB)

I sync my ODB with http://siteA/. Due to business reasons, I have migrated the site to http://siteB/ and I have performed necessary redirection using IIS URL REWRITE. So user trying to access **siteA** doc library will automatically be redirected **siteB** doc library. Everything works fine with the browser.

But after the migration, ODB stops working and fails to sync with the newly migrated site automatically.

Is there a way to achieve this automatically, Without reconfiguring ODB again ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to reconfiguring ODB. OneDrive for Business will not change the path to the new migrated site automatically. It is by design.

Comment: Thanks, Joanna. Is there any official confirmation by MS? When I tracked down by Fiddler, ODB receives the 301 status code while accessing siteA/_vti_bin/webs.asmx and do nothing.